# How do I generate a TextMate language grammar for Maximo/Jython from Java Packages for use in a VSCode extension

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, jython, textmate, maximo

I use Visual Studio Code to write Jython scripts for an Enterprise Asset Management System called IBM Maximo.  For anyone not familiar with it, Maximo is a Java application utilising IBM Websphere or Oracle Weblogic for the application server and MS SQL Server, Oracle or DB2 for the database back-end. The Jython scripts used to customise Maximo utilise a syntax which whilst very similar to Python, has a few distinct differences such as a more limited set of Python import libraries than vanilla Python, the availability of some built-in objects & variables from Maximo and the ability to import and utlise a set of Java packages for interacting with the Maximo application.  IBM provides documentation for their API in the form of HTML files which appear to be generated using the Java Standard Doclet:

https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/5692916

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/standard-doclet.html

Since there are no existing VSCode extensions for Jython or the specific flavour of Maximo Jython I am considering creating one using an existing extension for Python as a starting point then customising it to provide support for the Jython language and the syntax for the Maximo API. Visual Studio Code appears to use TextMate Grammars for syntax highlighting written as plist (XML) or JSON files.

As there are approximately 780 Java packages included in the Maximo API and these will no doubt change over time, I am looking for a way to automate the process of generating TextMate plist (XML) or JSON files from a set of Java packages using either a custom Java doclet or other process.  Is it possible to do this and if so how?

Comment: Could you provide more information about what are you trying to achieve ? An example would be helpful.

Comment: I think you need to implement Intellisense instead of TextMate syntax highlighting.